# Why does Dataflow show Protobuf error messages on any Datastore error?

Tags: google-cloud-datastore, google-cloud-dataflow

I have a simple Dataflow that copies from one Datastore to another. It generally succeeded, but on Kind __BlobInfo__ fails as follows. The entities in __BlobInfo__ are of course an essential part of user data, and I need to read and write them. What is happening?

Apparently __BlobInfo__ is a system Kind, protected from user writes

How can I get a clearer message?

(Edit: The answer is to remove this from pom.xml: com.google.apis.google-api-services-datastore-protobuf, v1beta2-rev1-4.0. That exposes the underlying problem, which is that this is a system Kind that does not allow writing.)

```
(bf8ac4ef49c1fcb5): 
java.lang.RuntimeException: com.google.cloud.dataflow.sdk.util.UserCodeException: 
java.lang.RuntimeException: com.google.cloud.dataflow.sdk.util.UserCodeException: 
java.lang.RuntimeException: com.google.cloud.dataflow.sdk.util.UserCodeException: 
java.lang.RuntimeException: com.google.cloud.dataflow.sdk.util.UserCodeException: 
java.lang.RuntimeException: com.google.cloud.dataflow.sdk.util.UserCodeException: 
java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.google.protobuf.GeneratedMessage.parseWithIOException(
Lcom/google/protobuf/Parser;Ljava/io/InputStream;)Lcom/google/protobuf/Message; at
com.google.cloud.dataflow.sdk.runners.worker.SimpleParDoFn$1.output(SimpleParDoFn.java:162) at
com.google.cloud.dataflow.sdk.util.DoFnRunnerBase$DoFnContext.outputWindowedValue(DoFnRunnerBase.java:287) at
com.google.cloud.dataflow.sdk.util.DoFnRunnerBase$DoFnContext.outputWindowedValue(DoFnRunnerBase.java:283) at
com.google.cloud.dataflow.sdk.util.DoFnRunnerBase$DoFnProcessContext$1.outputWindowedValue(DoFnRunnerBase.java:507) at
com.google.cloud.dataflow.sdk.util.GroupAlsoByWindowsViaIteratorsDoFn.processElement(GroupAlsoByWindowsViaIteratorsDoFn.java:125) at
com.google.cloud.dataflow.sdk.util.SimpleDoFnRunner.invokeProcessElement(SimpleDoFnRunner.java:49) at
com.google.cloud.dataflow.sdk.util.DoFnRunnerBase.processElement(DoFnRunnerBase.java:138) at
com.google.cloud.dataflow.sdk.runners.worker.SimpleParDoFn.processElement(SimpleParDoFn.java:190) at
com.google.cloud.dataflow.sdk.runners.worker.ForwardingParDoFn.processElement(ForwardingParDoFn.java:42) at
com.google.cloud.dataflow.sdk.runners.worker.DataflowWorkerLoggingParDoFn.processElement(DataflowWorkerLoggingParDoFn.java:47) at
com.google.cloud.dataflow.sdk.util.common.worker.ParDoOperation.process(ParDoOperation.java:55) at
com.google.cloud.dataflow.sdk.util.common.worker.OutputReceiver.process(OutputReceiver.java:52) at
com.google.cloud.dataflow.sdk.util.common.worker.ReadOperation.runReadLoop(ReadOperation.java:202) at
com.google.cloud.dataflow.sdk.util.common.worker.ReadOperation.start(ReadOperation.java:143) at
com.google.cloud.dataflow.sdk.util.common.worker.MapTaskExecutor.execute(MapTaskExecutor.java:72) at
com.google.cloud.dataflow.sdk.runners.worker.DataflowWorker.executeWork(DataflowWorker.java:287) at
com.google.cloud.dataflow.sdk.runners.worker.DataflowWorker.doWork(DataflowWorker.java:223) at
com.google.cloud.dataflow.sdk.runners.worker.DataflowWorker.getAndPerformWork(DataflowWorker.java:173) at
com.google.cloud.dataflow.sdk.runners.worker.DataflowWorkerHarness$WorkerThread.doWork(DataflowWorkerHarness.java:193) at
com.google.cloud.dataflow.sdk.runners.worker.DataflowWorkerHarness$WorkerThread.call(DataflowWorkerHarness.java:173) at
com.google.cloud.dataflow.sdk.runners.worker.DataflowWorkerHarness$WorkerThread.call(DataflowWorkerHarness.java:160) at
java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266) at
java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142) at
java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617) at
java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) Caused by: com.google.cloud.dataflow.sdk.util.UserCodeException: 
java.lang.RuntimeException: com.google.cloud.dataflow.sdk.util.UserCodeException: 
java.lang.RuntimeException: com.google.cloud.dataflow.sdk.util.UserCodeException: 
java.lang.RuntimeException: com.google.cloud.dataflow.sdk.util.UserCodeException: 
java.lang.RuntimeException: com.google.cloud.dataflow.sdk.util.UserCodeException: 
java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.google.protobuf.GeneratedMessage.parseWithIOException(Lcom/google/protobuf/Parser;Ljava/io/InputStream;)Lcom/google/protobuf/Message; at
com.google.cloud.dataflow.sdk.util.UserCodeException.wrap(UserCodeException.java:35) at
com.google.cloud.dataflow.sdk.util.UserCodeException.wrapIf(UserCodeException.java:40) at
com.google.cloud.dataflow.sdk.util.DoFnRunnerBase.wrapUserCodeException(DoFnRunnerBase.java:368) at
com.google.cloud.dataflow.sdk.util.SimpleDoFnRunner.invokeProcessElement(SimpleDoFnRunner.java:51) at
com.google.cloud.dataflow.sdk.util.DoFnRunnerBase.processElement(DoFnRunnerBase.java:138) at
com.google.cloud.dataflow.sdk.runners.worker.SimpleParDoFn.processElement(SimpleParDoFn.java:190) at
com.google.cloud.dataflow.sdk.runners.worker.ForwardingParDoFn.processElement(ForwardingParDoFn.java:42) at
com.google.cloud.dataflow.sdk.runners.worker.DataflowWorkerLoggingParDoFn.processElement(DataflowWorkerLoggingParDoFn.java:47) at
com.google.cloud.dataflow.sdk.util.common.worker.ParDoOperation.process(ParDoOperation.java:55) at
com.google.cloud.dataflow.sdk.util.common.worker.OutputReceiver.process(OutputReceiver.java:52) at
com.google.cloud.dataflow.sdk.runners.worker.SimpleParDoFn$1.output(SimpleParDoFn.java:160) ... 24 more Caused by: 
java.lang.RuntimeException: com.google.cloud.dataflow.sdk.util.UserCodeException: 
java.lang.RuntimeException: com.google.cloud.dataflow.sdk.util.UserCodeException: 
java.lang.RuntimeException: com.google.cloud.dataflow.sdk.util.UserCodeException: 
java.lang.RuntimeException: com.google.cloud.dataflow.sdk.util.UserCodeException: 
java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.google.protobuf.GeneratedMessage.parseWithIOException(Lcom/google/protobuf/Parser;Ljava/io/InputStream;)Lcom/google/protobuf/Message; at
com.google.cloud.dataflow.sdk.runners.worker.SimpleParDoFn$1.output(SimpleParDoFn.java:162) at
com.google.cloud.dataflow.sdk.util.DoFnRunnerBase$DoFnContext.outputWindowedValue(DoFnRunnerBase.java:287) at
com.google.cloud.dataflow.sdk.util.DoFnRunnerBase$DoFnProcessContext.output(DoFnRunnerBase.java:449) at
com.google.cloud.dataflow.sdk.transforms.Values$1.processElement(Values.java:64) Caused by: com.google.cloud.dataflow.sdk.util.UserCodeException: 
java.lang.RuntimeException: com.google.cloud.dataflow.sdk.util.UserCodeException: 
java.lang.RuntimeException: com.google.cloud.dataflow.sdk.util.UserCodeException: 
java.lang.RuntimeException: com.google.cloud.dataflow.sdk.util.UserCodeException: 
java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.google.protobuf.GeneratedMessage.parseWithIOException(Lcom/google/protobuf/Parser;Ljava/io/InputStream;)Lcom/google/protobuf/Message; at
com.google.cloud.dataflow.sdk.util.UserCodeException.wrap(UserCodeException.java:35) at
com.google.cloud.dataflow.sdk.util.UserCodeException.wrapIf(UserCodeException.java:40) at
com.google.cloud.dataflow.sdk.util.DoFnRunnerBase.wrapUserCodeException(DoFnRunnerBase.java:368) at
com.google.cloud.dataflow.sdk.util.SimpleDoFnRunner.invokeProcessElement(SimpleDoFnRunner.java:51) at
com.google.cloud.dataflow.sdk.util.DoFnRunnerBase.processElement(DoFnRunnerBase.java:138) at
com.google.cloud.dataflow.sdk.runners.worker.SimpleParDoFn.processElement(SimpleParDoFn.java:190) at
com.google.cloud.dataflow.sdk.runners.worker.ForwardingParDoFn.processElement(ForwardingParDoFn.java:42) at
com.google.cloud.dataflow.sdk.runners.worker.DataflowWorkerLoggingParDoFn.processElement(DataflowWorkerLoggingParDoFn.java:47) at
com.google.cloud.dataflow.sdk.util.common.worker.ParDoOperation.process(ParDoOperation.java:55) at
com.google.cloud.dataflow.sdk.util.common.worker.OutputReceiver.process(OutputReceiver.java:52) at
com.google.cloud.dataflow.sdk.runners.worker.SimpleParDoFn$1.output(SimpleParDoFn.java:160) at
com.google.cloud.dataflow.sdk.util.DoFnRunnerBase$DoFnContext.outputWindowedValue(DoFnRunnerBase.java:287) at
com.google.cloud.dataflow.sdk.util.DoFnRunnerBase$DoFnProcessContext.output(DoFnRunnerBase.java:449) at
com.google.cloud.dataflow.sdk.transforms.Values$1.processElement(Values.java:64) at
com.google.cloud.dataflow.sdk.util.SimpleDoFnRunner.invokeProcessElement(SimpleDoFnRunner.java:49) at
com.google.cloud.dataflow.sdk.util.DoFnRunnerBase.processElement(DoFnRunnerBase.java:138) at
com.google.cloud.dataflow.sdk.runners.worker.SimpleParDoFn.processElement(SimpleParDoFn.java:190) at
com.google.cloud.dataflow.sdk.runners.worker.ForwardingParDoFn.processElement(ForwardingParDoFn.java:42) at
com.google.cloud.dataflow.sdk.runners.worker.DataflowWorkerLoggingParDoFn.processElement(DataflowWorkerLoggingParDoFn.java:47) at
com.google.cloud.dataflow.sdk.util.common.worker.ParDoOperation.process(ParDoOperation.java:55) at
com.google.cloud.dataflow.sdk.util.common.worker.OutputReceiver.process(OutputReceiver.java:52) at
com.google.cloud.dataflow.sdk.runners.worker.SimpleParDoFn$1.output(SimpleParDoFn.java:160) at
com.google.cloud.dataflow.sdk.util.DoFnRunnerBase$DoFnContext.outputWindowedValue(DoFnRunnerBase.java:287) at
com.google.cloud.dataflow.sdk.util.DoFnRunnerBase$DoFnContext.outputWindowedValue(DoFnRunnerBase.java:283) at
com.google.cloud.dataflow.sdk.util.DoFnRunnerBase$DoFnProcessContext$1.outputWindowedValue(DoFnRunnerBase.java:507) at
com.google.cloud.dataflow.sdk.util.GroupAlsoByWindowsViaIteratorsDoFn.processElement(GroupAlsoByWindowsViaIteratorsDoFn.java:125) at
com.google.cloud.dataflow.sdk.util.SimpleDoFnRunner.invokeProcessElement(SimpleDoFnRunner.java:49) at
com.google.cloud.dataflow.sdk.util.DoFnRunnerBase.processElement(DoFnRunnerBase.java:138) at
com.google.cloud.dataflow.sdk.runners.worker.SimpleParDoFn.processElement(SimpleParDoFn.java:190) at
com.google.cloud.dataflow.sdk.runners.worker.ForwardingParDoFn.processElement(ForwardingParDoFn.java:42) at
com.google.cloud.dataflow.sdk.runners.worker.DataflowWorkerLoggingParDoFn.processElement(DataflowWorkerLoggingParDoFn.java:47) at
com.google.cloud.dataflow.sdk.util.common.worker.ParDoOperation.process(ParDoOperation.java:55) at
com.google.cloud.dataflow.sdk.util.common.worker.OutputReceiver.process(OutputReceiver.java:52) at
com.google.cloud.dataflow.sdk.util.common.worker.ReadOperation.runReadLoop(ReadOperation.java:202) at
com.google.cloud.dataflow.sdk.util.common.worker.ReadOperation.start(ReadOperation.java:143) at
com.google.cloud.dataflow.sdk.util.common.worker.MapTaskExecutor.execute(MapTaskExecutor.java:72) at
com.google.cloud.dataflow.sdk.runners.worker.DataflowWorker.executeWork(DataflowWorker.java:287) at
com.google.cloud.dataflow.sdk.runn
```

---

```
--- maven-dependency-plugin:2.8:tree (default-cli) @ dataflowbackup ---
com.freightos:dataflowbackup:war:1.0-SNAPSHOT
+- javax.servlet:javax.servlet-api:jar:3.1.0:compile
+- com.google.cloud.dataflow:google-cloud-dataflow-java-sdk-all:jar:1.7.0:compile
|  +- com.google.apis:google-api-services-dataflow:jar:v1b3-rev36-1.22.0:compile
|  |  \- (com.google.api-client:google-api-client:jar:1.22.0:compile - omitted for duplicate)
|  +- io.grpc:grpc-all:jar:0.13.1:compile
|  |  +- io.grpc:grpc-auth:jar:0.13.1:compile
|  |  |  +- (io.grpc:grpc-core:jar:0.13.1:compile - omitted for duplicate)
|  |  |  \- (com.google.auth:google-auth-library-oauth2-http:jar:0.3.0:compile - omitted for conflict with 0.4.0)
|  |  +- io.grpc:grpc-netty:jar:0.13.1:compile
|  |  |  +- io.netty:netty-codec-http2:jar:4.1.0.CR1:compile
|  |  |  |  +- io.netty:netty-codec-http:jar:4.1.0.CR1:compile
|  |  |  |  |  \- (io.netty:netty-codec:jar:4.1.0.CR1:compile - omitted for duplicate)
|  |  |  |  \- (io.netty:netty-handler:jar:4.1.0.CR1:compile - omitted for duplicate)
|  |  |  \- (io.grpc:grpc-core:jar:0.13.1:compile - omitted for duplicate)
|  |  +- io.grpc:grpc-protobuf:jar:0.13.1:compile
|  |  |  +- (com.google.protobuf:protobuf-java:jar:3.0.0-beta-2:compile - omitted for conflict with 3.0.0-beta-1)
|  |  |  +- (com.google.guava:guava:jar:18.0:compile - omitted for conflict with 19.0)
|  |  |  \- (io.grpc:grpc-core:jar:0.13.1:compile - omitted for duplicate)
|  |  +- io.grpc:grpc-core:jar:0.13.1:compile
|  |  |  +- (com.google.guava:guava:jar:18.0:compile - omitted for duplicate)
|  |  |  \- (com.google.code.findbugs:jsr305:jar:3.0.0:compile - omitted for conflict with 3.0.1)
|  |  +- io.grpc:grpc-okhttp:jar:0.13.1:compile
|  |  |  +- com.squareup.okio:okio:jar:1.6.0:compile
|  |  |  +- (io.grpc:grpc-core:jar:0.13.1:compile - omitted for duplicate)
|  |  |  \- com.squareup.okhttp:okhttp:jar:2.5.0:compile
|  |  |     \- (com.squareup.okio:okio:jar:1.6.0:compile - omitted for duplicate)
|  |  +- io.grpc:grpc-protobuf-nano:jar:0.13.1:compile
|  |  |  +- (com.google.guava:guava:jar:18.0:compile - omitted for duplicate)
|  |  |  +- com.google.protobuf.nano:protobuf-javanano:jar:3.0.0-alpha-5:compile
|  |  |  \- (io.grpc:grpc-core:jar:0.13.1:compile - omitted for duplicate)
|  |  \- io.grpc:grpc-stub:jar:0.13.1:compile
|  |     \- (io.grpc:grpc-core:jar:0.13.1:compile - omitted for duplicate)
|  +- io.netty:netty-handler:jar:4.1.0.CR1:compile
|  |  +- io.netty:netty-buffer:jar:4.1.0.CR1:compile
|  |  |  \- io.netty:netty-common:jar:4.1.0.CR1:compile
|  |  +- io.netty:netty-transport:jar:4.1.0.CR1:compile
|  |  |  +- (io.netty:netty-buffer:jar:4.1.0.CR1:compile - omitted for duplicate)
|  |  |  \- io.netty:netty-resolver:jar:4.1.0.CR1:compile
|  |  |     \- (io.netty:netty-common:jar:4.1.0.CR1:compile - omitted for duplicate)
|  |  \- io.netty:netty-codec:jar:4.1.0.CR1:compile
|  |     \- (io.netty:netty-transport:jar:4.1.0.CR1:compile - omitted for duplicate)
|  +- com.google.api.grpc:grpc-pubsub-v1:jar:0.0.2:compile
|  |  +- com.google.api.grpc:grpc-core-proto:jar:0.0.3:compile
|  |  |  +- (com.google.protobuf:protobuf-java:jar:3.0.0-beta-1:compile - omitted for conflict with 3.0.0-beta-2)
|  |  |  +- (io.grpc:grpc-stub:jar:0.12.0:compile - omitted for conflict with 0.13.1)
|  |  |  \- (io.grpc:grpc-protobuf:jar:0.12.0:compile - omitted for conflict with 0.13.1)
|  |  \- (io.grpc:grpc-all:jar:0.12.0:compile - omitted for conflict with 0.13.1)
|  +- com.google.auth:google-auth-library-oauth2-http:jar:0.4.0:compile
|  |  +- com.google.auth:google-auth-library-credentials:jar:0.4.0:compile
|  |  +- (com.google.http-client:google-http-client:jar:1.19.0:compile - omitted for conflict with 1.22.0)
|  |  \- (com.google.http-client:google-http-client-jackson2:jar:1.19.0:compile - omitted for conflict with 1.22.0)
|  +- com.google.cloud.bigtable:bigtable-protos:jar:0.3.0:compile
|  |  +- (com.google.code.findbugs:jsr305:jar:3.0.1:compile - omitted for duplicate)
|  |  +- (com.google.protobuf:protobuf-java:jar:3.0.0-beta-1:compile - omitted for duplicate)
|  |  +- (io.grpc:grpc-core:jar:0.13.1:compile - omitted for duplicate)
|  |  +- (io.grpc:grpc-stub:jar:0.13.1:compile - omitted for duplicate)
|  |  +- (io.grpc:grpc-protobuf:jar:0.13.1:compile - omitted for duplicate)
|  |  \- (com.google.guava:guava:jar:19.0:compile - omitted for conflict with 12.0)
|  +- com.google.api-client:google-api-client:jar:1.22.0:compile
|  |  +- (com.google.oauth-client:google-oauth-client:jar:1.22.0:compile - omitted for duplicate)
|  |  \- (com.google.http-client:google-http-client-jackson2:jar:1.22.0:compile - omitted for conflict with 1.19.0)
|  +- (com.google.api-client:google-api-client-java6:jar:1.22.0:compile - scope updated from runtime; omitted for duplicate)
|  +- (com.google.api-client:google-api-client-jackson2:jar:1.22.0:compile - scope updated from runtime; omitted for duplicate)
|  +- com.google.apis:google-api-services-bigquery:jar:v2-rev295-1.22.0:compile
|  |  \- (com.google.api-client:google-api-client:jar:1.22.0:compile - omitted for duplicate)
|  +- com.google.apis:google-api-services-clouddebugger:jar:v2-rev8-1.22.0:compile
|  |  \- (com.google.api-client:google-api-client:jar:1.22.0:compile - omitted for duplicate)
|  +- com.google.apis:google-api-services-pubsub:jar:v1-rev10-1.22.0:compile
|  |  \- (com.google.api-client:google-api-client:jar:1.22.0:compile - omitted for duplicate)
|  +- com.google.apis:google-api-services-storage:jar:v1-rev71-1.22.0:compile
|  |  \- (com.google.api-client:google-api-client:jar:1.22.0:compile - omitted for duplicate)
|  +- com.google.http-client:google-http-client:jar:1.22.0:compile
|  |  +- (com.google.code.findbugs:jsr305:jar:1.3.9:compile - omitted for conflict with 3.0.1)
|  |  \- org.apache.httpcomponents:httpclient:jar:4.0.1:compile
|  |     +- org.apache.httpcomponents:httpcore:jar:4.0.1:compile
|  |     +- commons-logging:commons-logging:jar:1.1.1:compile
|  |     \- commons-codec:commons-codec:jar:1.3:compile
|  +- (com.google.http-client:google-http-client-jackson:jar:1.22.0:compile - scope updated from runtime; omitted for duplicate)
|  +- com.google.http-client:google-http-client-jackson2:jar:1.22.0:compile
|  |  +- (com.google.http-client:google-http-client:jar:1.22.0:compile - omitted for duplicate)
|  |  \- (com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-core:jar:2.1.3:compile - omitted for conflict with 2.7.0)
|  +- (com.google.http-client:google-http-client-protobuf:jar:1.22.0:compile - scope updated from runtime; omitted for duplicate)
|  +- com.google.oauth-client:google-oauth-client-java6:jar:1.22.0:compile
|  |  \- (com.google.oauth-client:google-oauth-client:jar:1.22.0:compile - omitted for duplicate)
|  +- com.google.oauth-client:google-oauth-client:jar:1.22.0:compile
|  |  +- (com.google.http-client:google-http-client:jar:1.22.0:compile - omitted for duplicate)
|  |  \- (com.google.code.findbugs:jsr305:jar:1.3.9:compile - omitted for conflict with 3.0.1)
|  +- (com.google.apis:google-api-services-datastore-protobuf:jar:v1beta2-rev1-4.0.0:compile - omitted for duplicate)
|  +- com.google.cloud.bigdataoss:gcsio:jar:1.4.5:compile
|  |  +- com.google.api-client:google-api-client-java6:jar:1.22.0:compile
|  |  |  +- (com.google.api-client:google-api-client:jar:1.20.0:compile - omitted for conflict with 1.22.0)
|  |  |  \- (com.google.oauth-client:google-oauth-client-java6:jar:1.20.0:compile - omitted for conflict with 1.22.0)
|  |  +- com.google.api-client:google-api-client-jackson2:jar:1.22.0:compile
|  |  |  +- (com.google.api-client:google-api-client:jar:1.20.0:compile - omitted for conflict with 1.22.0)
|  |  |  \- (com.google.http-client:google-http-client-jackson2:jar:1.20.0:compile - omitted for conflict with 1.22.0)
|  |  +- (com.google.apis:google-api-services-storage:jar:v1-rev35-1.20.0:compile - omitted for conflict with v1-rev71-1.22.0)
|  |  +- (com.google.code.findbugs:jsr305:jar:2.0.3:compile - omitted for conflict with 3.0.1)
|  |  +- (com.google.guava:guava:jar:18.0:compile - omitted for conflict with 19.0)
|  |  +- (com.google.oauth-client:google-oauth-client:jar:1.20.0:compile - omitted for conflict with 1.22.0)
|  |  +- (com.google.oauth-client:google-oauth-client-java6:jar:1.20.0:compile - omitted for conflict with 1.22.0)
|  |  \- (com.google.cloud.bigdataoss:util:jar:1.4.5:compile - omitted for duplicate)
|  +- com.google.cloud.datastore:datastore-v1-proto-client:jar:1.1.0:compile
|  |  +- (com.google.cloud.datastore:datastore-v1-protos:jar:1.0.1:compile - omitted for duplicate)
|  |  +- (com.google.http-client:google-http-client:jar:1.20.0:compile - omitted for conflict with 1.22.0)
|  |  +- (com.google.http-client:google-http-client-protobuf:jar:1.22.0:compile - omitted for conflict with 1.15.0-rc)
|  |  +- (com.google.http-client:google-http-client-jackson:jar:1.22.0:compile - omitted for conflict with 1.15.0-rc)
|  |  +- (com.google.oauth-client:google-oauth-client:jar:1.20.0:compile - omitted for conflict with 1.22.0)
|  |  +- (com.google.api-client:google-api-client:jar:1.20.0:compile - omitted for conflict with 1.22.0)
|  |  \- (com.google.guava:guava:jar:18.0:compile - omitted for conflict with 19.0)
|  +- com.google.cloud.datastore:datastore-v1-protos:jar:1.0.1:compile
|  |  \- (com.google.protobuf:protobuf-java:jar:3.0.0-beta-1:compile - omitted for duplicate)
|  +- com.google.cloud.bigdataoss:util:jar:1.4.5:compile
|  |  +- (com.google.api-client:google-api-client-java6:jar:1.20.0:compile - omitted for conflict with 1.22.0)
|  |  +- (com.google.api-client:google-api-client-jackson2:jar:1.20.0:compile - omitted for conflict with 1.22.0)
|  |  +- (com.google.apis:google-api-services-storage:jar:v1-rev35-1.20.0:compile - omitted for conflict with v1-rev71-1.22.0)
|  |  +- (com.google.code.findbugs:jsr305:jar:2.0.3:compile - omitted for conflict with 3.0.1)
|  |  +- (com.google.guava:guava:jar:18.0:compile - omitted for conflict with 19.0)
|  |  +- (com.google.oauth-client:google-oauth-client:jar:1.20.0:compile - omitted for conflict with 1.22.0)
|  |  \- (com.google.oauth-client:google-oauth-client-java6:jar:1.20.0:compile - omitted for conflict with 1.22.0)
|  +- com.google.protobuf:protobuf-java:jar:3.0.0-beta-1:compile
|  +- com.google.code.findbugs:jsr305:jar:3.0.1:compile
|  +- com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-core:jar:2.7.0:compile
|  +- com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-annotations:jar:2.7.0:compile
|  +- com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-databind:jar:2.7.0:compile
|  |  +- (com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-annotations:jar:2.7.0:compile - omitted for duplicate)
|  |  \- (com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-core:jar:2.7.0:compile - omitted for duplicate)
|  +- (org.slf4j:slf4j-api:jar:1.7.14:compile - omitted for conflict with 1.7.7)
|  +- org.apache.avro:avro:jar:1.7.7:compile
|  |  +- org.codehaus.jackson:jackson-core-asl:jar:1.9.13:compile
|  |  +- org.codehaus.jackson:jackson-mapper-asl:jar:1.9.13:compile
|  |  |  \- (org.codehaus.jackson:jackson-core-asl:jar:1.9.13:compile - omitted for duplicate)
|  |  +- com.thoughtworks.paranamer:paranamer:jar:2.3:compile
|  |  +- (org.xerial.snappy:snappy-java:jar:1.0.5:compile - omitted for conflict with 1.1.2.1)
|  |  +- (org.apache.commons:commons-compress:jar:1.4.1:compile - omitted for conflict with 1.9)
|  |  \- (org.slf4j:slf4j-api:jar:1.6.4:compile - omitted for conflict with 1.7.14)
|  +- (org.xerial.snappy:snappy-java:jar:1.1.2.1:compile - omitted for conflict with 1.1.2.6)
|  +- org.apache.commons:commons-compress:jar:1.9:compile
|  \- joda-time:joda-time:jar:2.4:compile
+- org.xerial.snappy:snappy-java:jar:1.1.2.6:compile
+- com.google.apis:google-api-services-datastore-protobuf:jar:v1beta2-rev1-4.0.0:compile
|  +- (com.google.protobuf:protobuf-java:jar:3.0.0-beta-1:compile - omitted for duplicate)
|  +- (com.google.http-client:google-http-client:jar:1.15.0-rc:compile - omitted for conflict with 1.22.0)
|  +- com.google.http-client:google-http-client-protobuf:jar:1.15.0-rc:compile
|  |  +- (com.google.http-client:google-http-client:jar:1.15.0-rc:compile - omitted for conflict with 1.22.0)
|  |  \- (com.google.protobuf:protobuf-java:jar:2.4.1:compile - omitted for conflict with 3.0.0-beta-1)
|  +- com.google.http-client:google-http-client-jackson:jar:1.15.0-rc:compile
|  |  +- (com.google.http-client:google-http-client:jar:1.15.0-rc:compile - omitted for conflict with 1.22.0)
|  |  \- (org.codehaus.jackson:jackson-core-asl:jar:1.9.11:compile - omitted for conflict with 1.9.13)
|  +- (com.google.oauth-client:google-oauth-client:jar:1.15.0-rc:compile - omitted for conflict with 1.22.0)
|  +- (com.google.api-client:google-api-client:jar:1.15.0-rc:compile - omitted for conflict with 1.22.0)
|  \- (com.google.guava:guava:jar:12.0:compile - omitted for conflict with 19.0)
+- org.apache.commons:commons-lang3:jar:3.4:compile
+- junit:junit:jar:4.12:compile
|  \- org.hamcrest:hamcrest-core:jar:1.3:compile
+- org.slf4j:slf4j-api:jar:1.7.7:compile
+- org.slf4j:slf4j-jdk14:jar:1.7.7:runtime
|  \- (org.slf4j:slf4j-api:jar:1.7.7:runtime - omitted for duplicate)
+- com.google.cloud:gcloud-java-datastore:jar:0.2.8:compile
|  +- com.google.cloud:gcloud-java-core:jar:0.2.8:compile
|  |  +- (com.google.auth:google-auth-library-credentials:jar:0.3.1:compile - omitted for conflict with 0.4.0)
|  |  +- (com.google.auth:google-auth-library-oauth2-http:jar:0.3.1:compile - omitted for conflict with 0.4.0)
|  |  +- (com.google.http-client:google-http-client:jar:1.21.0:compile - omitted for conflict with 1.22.0)
|  |  +- (com.google.oauth-client:google-oauth-client:jar:1.21.0:compile - omitted for conflict with 1.22.0)
|  |  +- (com.google.guava:guava:jar:19.0:compile - omitted for conflict with 12.0)
|  |  +- com.google.api-client:google-api-client-appengine:jar:1.21.0:compile
|  |  |  +- com.google.oauth-client:google-oauth-client-appengine:jar:1.21.0:compile
|  |  |  |  +- (com.google.http-client:google-http-client-appengine:jar:1.21.0:compile - omitted for duplicate)
|  |  |  |  +- (com.google.oauth-client:google-oauth-client:jar:1.21.0:compile - omitted for conflict with 1.22.0)
|  |  |  |  +- com.google.oauth-client:google-oauth-client-servlet:jar:1.21.0:compile
|  |  |  |  |  +- (com.google.oauth-client:google-oauth-client:jar:1.21.0:compile - omitted for conflict with 1.22.0)
|  |  |  |  |  +- com.google.http-client:google-http-client-jdo:jar:1.21.0:compile
|  |  |  |  |  |  +- (com.google.http-client:google-http-client:jar:1.21.0:compile - omitted for conflict with 1.22.0)
|  |  |  |  |  |  \- (javax.jdo:jdo2-api:jar:2.3-eb:compile - omitted for duplicate)
|  |  |  |  |  +- (javax.servlet:servlet-api:jar:2.5:compile - omitted for duplicate)
|  |  |  |  |  \- (javax.jdo:jdo2-api:jar:2.3-eb:compile - omitted for duplicate)
|  |  |  |  \- javax.servlet:servlet-api:jar:2.5:compile
|  |  |  +- (com.google.api-client:google-api-client:jar:1.21.0:compile - omitted for conflict with 1.22.0)
|  |  |  +- com.google.api-client:google-api-client-servlet:jar:1.21.0:compile
|  |  |  |  +- (com.google.oauth-client:google-oauth-client-servlet:jar:1.21.0:compile - omitted for duplicate)
|  |  |  |  +- (com.google.api-client:google-api-client:jar:1.21.0:compile - omitted for conflict with 1.22.0)
|  |  |  |  +- (javax.servlet:servlet-api:jar:2.5:compile - omitted for duplicate)
|  |  |  |  \- javax.jdo:jdo2-api:jar:2.3-eb:compile
|  |  |  |     \- javax.transaction:transaction-api:jar:1.1:compile
|  |  |  \- com.google.http-client:google-http-client-appengine:jar:1.21.0:compile
|  |  |     \- (com.google.http-client:google-http-client:jar:1.21.0:compile - omitted for conflict with 1.22.0)
|  |  +- (com.google.http-client:google-http-client-jackson:jar:1.21.0:compile - omitted for conflict with 1.15.0-rc)
|  |  +- (joda-time:joda-time:jar:2.9.2:compile - omitted for conflict with 2.4)
|  |  +- org.json:json:jar:20151123:compile
|  |  +- (com.google.protobuf:protobuf-java:jar:3.0.0-beta-3:compile - omitted for conflict with 3.0.0-beta-1)
|  |  +- com.google.api:gax:jar:0.0.14:compile
|  |  |  +- (io.grpc:grpc-all:jar:0.15.0:compile - omitted for conflict with 0.13.1)
|  |  |  +- com.google.auto.value:auto-value:jar:1.1:compile
|  |  |  +- (com.google.guava:guava:jar:18.0:compile - omitted for conflict with 12.0)
|  |  |  +- (joda-time:joda-time:jar:2.8.2:compile - omitted for conflict with 2.4)
|  |  |  +- com.google.inject:guice:jar:4.0:compile
|  |  |  |  +- javax.inject:javax.inject:jar:1:compile
|  |  |  |  +- aopalliance:aopalliance:jar:1.0:compile
|  |  |  |  \- (com.google.guava:guava:jar:16.0.1:compile - omitted for conflict with 12.0)
|  |  |  +- (com.google.code.findbugs:jsr305:jar:3.0.0:compile - omitted for conflict with 3.0.1)
|  |  |  \- (com.google.auth:google-auth-library-oauth2-http:jar:0.4.0:compile - omitted for duplicate)
|  |  \- com.google.api.grpc:grpc-google-common-protos:jar:0.0.7:compile
|  |     +- (com.google.protobuf:protobuf-java:jar:3.0.0-beta-3:compile - omitted for conflict with 3.0.0-beta-1)
|  |     \- (io.grpc:grpc-all:jar:0.15.0:compile - omitted for conflict with 0.13.1)
|  +- (com.google.cloud.datastore:datastore-v1-protos:jar:1.0.1:compile - omitted for duplicate)
|  \- (com.google.cloud.datastore:datastore-v1-proto-client:jar:1.1.0:compile - omitted for duplicate)
\- com.google.guava:guava:jar:19.0:compile
```

Comment: Are you using DatastoreIO or your custom transform to read/write to Datastore?

Comment: @VikasKedigehalli

DatastoreIO.v1().read() and DatastoreIO.v1().write()

Comment: Is that all the stack trace you got? I don't see any DatastoreIO calls, wondering if they are getting truncated somehow.

Comment: Also, what version of proto are you using. That seems to be a proto related error.

Comment: @VikasKedigehall This is the dependency declared in Maven: com.google.apis.google-api-services-datastore-protobuf, version v1beta2-rev1-4.0.0 Also protobuf-java3.0.0-beta-1 and protobuf-javanano-3.0.0-alpha-5 are contained in the Maven dependency hierarchy

Comment: I think that is the problem. Could you instead change it to com.google.cloud.datastore:datastore-v1-protos? http://search.maven.org/#search%7Cga%7C1%7Ca%3A%22datastore-v1-protos%22 instead?.  com.google.apis.google-api-services-datastore-protobuf, version v1beta2-rev1-4.0.0 is not compatible with v1 version which is used in DatastoreIO.

Comment: In fact, the SDK should already pull the dependency, so you can just remove the com.google.apis.google-api-services-datastore-protobuf, version v1beta2-rev1-4.0.0 from you maven file.

Comment: v1beta2 is fine there, this is not going to be the issue. more investigation needed...

Comment: Dan is right. @JoshuaFox Could you crosscheck that protobuf 3.0.0-beta1 and datastore-v1-protos 1.0.1 are the ones actually being used from the maven dependency tree? Would be nice if you could paste the output of "mvn dependeny:tree --Dverbose=True"

Comment: @VikasKedigehalli Do you mean mvn --D verbose=true dependency:tree

Comment: @VikasKedigehalli  I added the tree to the body of the posting

Comment: @DanHalperin I just now found that a different underlying error generated a similar error message. That other error was caused by a permissions issue that I resolved. That makes me think that the protobuf message is secondary -- it is a problem in parsing some sort of error, but the underlying error is something else. Maybe permissions in trying to write to  _ _ Blobstore_info _ _ ? As noted, that is a "system" table -- yet it may be essential to copy it for a full backup.

Comment: @JoshuaFox Here is what I think might be happening: gcloud-java-datastore -> gcloud-java-core is using protobuf:3.0.0-beta3 while dataflow is using protobuf:3.0.0-beta1. 'parseWithIOException' is something that was added in 3.0.0-beta3. Somewhere there is a Proto message that is generated by a protobuf compiler 3.0.0-beta3, but at runtime the version of the protobuf is 3.0.0-beta1, and when this message being constructed we get this NoSuchMethodError.

Comment: @JoshuaFox Having said that, it is quite possible that there could be permission issues since __Blobstore_info__ is  a "system" table. But it would good to reproduce this problem in isolation and provide a better stack trace to the Datastore team. How about a simple program to read/write to __Blobstore_info__ using gcloud-java-datastore without involving Dataflow? That would give use more visibility and make it easy to find the right folks to debug this in more detail.

Comment: OK, I removed com.google.apis.google-api-services-datastore-protobuf, version v1beta2-rev1-4.0. and got a better exception message, thank you. 73878b9a4e31fa8e): com.google.datastore.v1.client.DatastoreException: The kind "__BlobInfo__" is reserved., code=INVALID_ARGUMENT at com.google.datastore.v1.client.RemoteRpc.makeException(RemoteRpc.java:126) at ..

Comment: @VikasKedigehalli Please add "remove com.google.apis.google-api-services-datastore-protobuf, version v1beta2-rev1-4.0" so I can Accept it (or I can do that, but  you should get the karma.)

Comment: @VikasKedigehalli FWIW, the problematic dependency probably snuck in from an earlier version of https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/DataflowJavaSDK/blob/master/pom.xml . Apparently that has been fixed since then.

Comment: @JoshuaFox Glad that it worked for you but I am not entirely convinced with removing v1beta2. We have it always working with datastore v1beta2 and v1 being compiled together with maven. I think the problem is still with protobuf 3.0.0-beta1 and 3.0.0-beta3 being used together (different ones at compile and runtime).

Comment: @VikasKedigehalli  In case it is useful to you: Here is the new output of 
mvn --D verbose=true dependency:tree
in the new sitation where the Protobuf error no longer occurs.

http://pastebin.com/PeAzMaQF